How do I instruct PowerShell to execute a local command?
Consider the following code:
mjml $inputPath | Set-Content $outputPath
If I define a function function mjml() { Write-Host "Hello" }, then the local command mjml is shadowed.
How can I instruct PowerShell to execute a local command, ignoring functions, alias, etc. with the same name?
Bonus: How can I tell PowerShell to do the same in case of another type of language construct (e.g. functions or aliases)?

You can specify the fully qualified path to the local command such as /usr/local/bin/mjml or 'C:\Program Files\mjml\mjml.exe'.

Thank you. But this makes a script less compatible with other systems

On Windows, the easiest way to always invoke the executable can be to append the .exe extension, i.e. mjml.exe, this of course fails if you're purposefully doing:
function mjml.exe { 'nope' }

In general, this goes to the bonus question, you can use Get-Command to get the specific CommandInfo derived instance (these can be FunctionInfo, CmdletInfo, ApplicationInfo, etc) and then invoke it via the call operator &.
For example:
PS ..\pwsh> function cmd { 'powershell func' }
PS ..\pwsh> cmd
powershell func
PS ..\pwsh> & (Get-Command cmd -CommandType Application) /c echo hello world
hello world

Same applies to target a function if there was an alias that overrides it (aliases have the highest precedence always):
PS ..\pwsh> function myFunc { 'hello' }
PS ..\pwsh> function otherFunc { 'other func' }
PS ..\pwsh> $alias:myFunc = 'otherFunc'
PS ..\pwsh> myFunc
other func
PS ..\pwsh> & (Get-Command myFunc -CommandType Function)
hello


Thank you. So, there is no equivalent of Bash’s command built-in?

What’s your “cmd” in the first example?

Its the actual cmd.exe @Shuzheng
